# What is the benefit of the ValueConversion attribute?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, msdn, ivalueconverter

I have no problems with the implementation of a `ValueConverter`.

On MSDN I found the `ValueConversion` attribute:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(DateTime), typeof(String))]
public class DateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
        return date.ToShortDateString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string strValue = value as string;
        DateTime resultDateTime;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(strValue, out resultDateTime))
        {
            return resultDateTime;
        }
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

and it would interest me:

- When can I use it?
- When should I use it?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: From MSDN: `When implementing the IValueConverter interface, it is a good practice to decorate the implementation with a ValueConversionAttribute attribute to indicate to development tools the data types involved in the conversion.`

Comment: @nemesv your're right, but I don't found this on so, thx My eyes must have been closed.

Comment: Also: `The ValueConversionAttribute attribute enables designer tools, such as Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) Designer for Visual Studio, to discover value converters to assist developers in setting up bindings. `